# what is a correct way to call std::forward<Func> more than once?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, perfect-forwarding

example: (it doesn't assume that `func` is pure, copy constructible or move constructible)

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void dispatch(std::vector<int>& cont, Func&& func){
    for (auto& v : cont)
        std::forward<Func>(func)(v);
}
```

in a standard practice, we should receive a function object by `Func&&` and then call it by `std::forward<Func>(func)(args...)`, to avoid any copy or move, and choose the correct overload of `operator()`. but there is a question: **what happens if `func` is a rvalue and its `operator() &&` moves itself?**

obviously, a possible result is, the **valid but indeterminate** `func` is called, which is an unspecified behavior, I think.

so how to avoid this problem? I think copy constructibility and purity is not an acceptable cost. what about calling `operator() &` n - 1 times and `operator() &&` once?

EDIT:

in this question, it doesn't depend on any real problem. it's just a thought experiment to find a more general way to deal with this situation.

and in the comment, I get some solutions:

1. passing by copy.
   but `Func` is not necessarily copy constructible or move constructible. even if it is, the solution is equal to call `operator() &`, why not use `func()` directly?
2. always calling `operator() &`.
   it seems like:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void dispatch(std::vector<int>& cont, Func&& func){
    for (auto& v : cont)
        func(v);
}
```

it's a good way to solve this problem, and always not give user any surprise. but I think it loses the rvalue property of `func`, and it may cause unnecessary copy:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void dispatch(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& cont, Func&& func){
    for (auto& vec : cont)
        func(vec);
}

template<typename T>
struct Assignable{
    T data;
    void operator()(T& v) const&{
        v = data;
    }
    void operator()(T& v) &&{
        v = std::move(data);
    }
};
template<typename T>
Assignable(T) -> Assignable<T>;

int main(){
    std::vector<int> a(10000, 100);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b(5);
    dispatch(b, Assignable{ std::move(a) });
}
```

the big vector `a` is actually copied 5 times, rather than copied 4 times and moved once, which is what we always do by enumeration. and in this case, I have no idea how to move `a`, unless don't use `dispatch`.

3. n-1 times `operator() &` and once `operator() &&`

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void dispatch(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& cont, Func&& func){
    for (auto begin = cont.begin(); begin + 1 < cont.end(); ++begin)
        func(*begin);
    if (!cont.empty())
        std::forward<Func>(func)(cont.back());
}

template<typename T>
struct Assignable{
    T data;
    void operator()(T& v) const&{
        v = data;
    }
    void operator()(T& v) &&{
        v = std::move(data);
    }
};
template<typename T>
Assignable(T) -> Assignable<T>;

int main(){
    std::vector<int> a(10000, 100);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> b(5);
    dispatch(b, Assignable{ std::move(a) });
}
```

in this case, `a` is correctly moved. the rvalue property of `func` is considered.

but in the other hand, this style is also thought against the POLA (principle of least astonishment), which implies that the user is confused about why `func` works differently each time.

so I wonder if it is the best way to show the rvalue property of `func`?

EDIT2:

I think it can be transmitted to another question:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&...){};

template<typename... Args>
void invoke_twice(Args&&... args){
    foo(/* ??? */);
    foo(/* ??? */);
}
```

what should we do in this case? it's exactly wrong if `forward` twice. and if we specify this problem:

```cpp
void foo(std::vector<int> const&){};
void foo(std::vector<int>&&){};

void invoke_twice(std::vector<int>&& cont){
    foo(/* ??? */);
    foo(/* ??? */);
}
```

it always is `foo(cont)` first, and then `foo(std::move(cont))`, isn't it?

in functional opinion, `Func::operator()(...) const&` means `operator()(Func const&, ...)`, and `Func::operator()(...) &&` means `operator()(Func&&, ...)`, so can we say that we should use `func(...)` first and then `std::forward<Func>(func)(...)`?

Comment: Do you have a good practical reason to take a functor by a `&&`? Why not to take it by value as the standard library functions do?

Comment: @TedLyngmo  if I want to use `operator() &`, just `func()` is ok, without any construction. using `std::forward<Func>(func)(args...)` is to allow `operator() &&` to be called. maybe you agree on calling `func()` as `operator() &` directly?

Comment: @Evg because `func` should not be assumed to be copy constructible or move constructible. functions in STL are demanded to be in some limitations (at least to be move constructible), but in my case, it's not necessary.

Comment: This question sounds like either an academic one or an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real practical problem you're trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: IMO, if you have a distinction between `operator()(...) &` and `operator()(...) &&`, then using `std::forward` only on the last value is against the [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). In this, and any other case you can simply call `operator()(...) &` on all values.

Comment: @Evg it can be thought not to depend on a real problem. I found a conflict between constructibility and `operator()` overloads in the earlier standard practice (`Func&&` and `std::forward`). I wonder if there is a new practice to solve this problem, or one of them must be not satisfied.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I don't see the point to possibly call move constructor, calling directly `func` seems fine [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vjETdz)

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed ... I shouldn't do this before 3 cups of coffee :-) ... cleaning up my garbage...

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to protect against. If your function object is only callable once, then it's only callable once, and no amount of handwaving will make it callable twice.

Comment: @BennyK I think it's a useful principle, but a problem exists in this case, such as the example in my edit.

Comment: You summarized the options adequately. Notice how you need ~15 additional lines of code to explain option 2. The functor you suggest is somewhat astonishing by itself, given that there are much better ways to reach the end result. I believe you should return to this question if and when you have a *practical* use case in mind.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. if `func` can be called more than once, it must have `operator() &`, because it may cause an unspecified behavior if `operator() &&` with side effects is called more than once. but that `operator() &` exists doesn't mean it should call `operator() &` all the time, so I ask this question how to deal with `operator() &&` in this situation.

Comment: Why do you think `operator() &` gives you any more guarantees? Or any other function for that matter?

Comment: The answer is to document your behaviour, let the user deal with it.